# Should, in a web app using a 3-tier design pattern, one of the bottom layers provide some checking mechanism to ensure…?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m trying to write a web app using 4-tier design pattern ( Data Store, DAL, BLL and UI).
Among other things this app would also implement a forum.

Suppose I want to move a thread from one forum to another. In order to do this, UI layer must pass down to other layers the ID of a thread and the ID of a forum to which I wish to move this thread ( UI would pass these parameters by calling method A in BLL layer and A would in turn call method B in DAL layer… ).

a) Now should one of the bottom layers provide some sort of checking mechanism to ensure that the two ID arguments supplied by UI layer really represent an existing thread and an existing forum or is it the responsibility of UI layer to provide valid ID values?

thanx

EDIT:

> I would consider the ability to pass invalid IDs a bug.

Should non existing ID be considered a bug just in the case of moving a thread, or also in the case of displaying a thread. Thus when user navigates to page Showthread.aspx?ID={0}, if query string parameter ID references non existing ID, If none of the layers check for the validity of ID, then GridView simply won’t display any

> “But in this case it doesn't look like the ids are in any sort of list. If they were one could only assume that this would never happen as I assume the lists would be populated by a stored procedure or a DAL procedure that pulls all valid IDs.”

But even if user chooses IDs from a set of list, by the time it posts the page back, the DB table containing this ID could be changed in the mean time by admin or whomever?!

Comment: Is the user selecting the forum and thread in a UI, or are you allowing them to simply enter in two IDs?

Comment: @carewithl - I would really hope that you are not letting the user type in an ID, populate a list or drop down then allow the user to select from only valid options.

Comment: I'm just trying to assume what would happen if some third party would actually want to build UI layer on top of the BLL and DAL layers I wrote. I'm just trying to figure out what do purchasers most often expect from DAL and BLL when it comes to handling these kinds of bugs.

Comment: @carewithl - Really depends, are you trying to sell software or keep it internally.  If the latter then you shouldn't be too concerned.  I highly doubt anyone is going to buy a DAL and a BLL for a specific application being that there are ORMs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean that noone will want to buy DAL or BLL due to ORMs? In other words, all the learning I did of  Ado.Net and the DAL/ BLL design patterns was/is in vain?

Comment: @carewithl - Nothing is in vain, because what you have done is learned how the technology works.  Data access layers and Business logic layers were very popular in the past.  People used to sit there and code their entire data access layer but it was a night mare.  It always grew in size, it was error prone, and most companies realized that it never could be reused (well without tweaking).  I am not saying you did this all for nothing, in the end you learned something.  What I am saying is developers use ORM (Object Relational Mapping) for DALs now.

Comment: @carewithl - To continue, I wanted to also mention that companies or other developers are not willing to buy DAL or BLL because they differ across app domains.  If you wrote a beautiful DAL that works perfectly fine for your database type and your application type what makes you think it would work for me or anyone for  that matter.  You'd end up tweaking it to fit my needs so in reality you just created another DAL.  So people do not sell DAL or BLL, they write them for what they use them for and that is it.  They may later on reuse them for similiar apps or to share code but they almost

Comment: @JonH: ORMs are not a panacea.  I use them lots, but I still find myself frequently writing direct-database code and encapsulating the combined ORM+DB functionality into some sort of middle tier, even in simpler apps.  In enterprise development, the replacement for the traditional BLL is actually SOA; ORM is just a tool (and SOA is not a panacea either, I'm just pointing it out).  "Business tiers" are still very much in use, and DALs may be easier to make but they are still separate layers.

Comment: @AAronaught - I agree my point was that you can hardly sell them (DAL and BLL).  Which the OP was asking about.

Comment: So in most cases I should use ORM instead of DAL and SOA instead of BLL?

Comment: ...No, that's not what either of us said.  There are no easy answers, there is no "most cases."  ORM is not a replacement for a DAL and SOA is not (really) a drop-in replacement for a BLL.  It's preferable to think of these concepts as simply a "persistence layer" and a "domain model" - it's entirely up to you to decide how they'll be implemented.

Comment: Uhm, if we implement ORM, then we usually won't  also implement DAL. So how is ORM not replacement for DAL?Perhaps it provides other functionality that DAL doesn't provide or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI->BLL->DAL
UI<-BLL<-DAL

Your database is not another layer its simply a repository of the data.  What you describe is your typical 3-tier architecture.  Layers are the assemblies (dll files) while tiers are the storage mechanism (hardware).  Some people might mix those terms up but ultimately it doesn't matter.

In this case your UI calls the BLL which in turn calls the DAL.
Once you process what you need from the DAL then the DAL takes that information and passes to the BLL (Business Logic Layer) which in turn submits back to your UI.

Your UI shouldn't know anything about a valid ID, that is your UI should not touch your DAL.  Pass the ID's to the BLL and the BLL can then check if they are valid.  Some folks like to actually check inside the DAL sproc level and return some sort of flag.

```
bool IsValid(int forumID) {
//call the dal to get a true or false based on this
bool isValid=false;
DAL d = new DAL();
isValid = d.IsValid(forumID);
return isValid;
}
```

And your DAL then has a function to simply call say a sproc to return true or false if the ID exists.

```
bool IsValid(int forumID){
bool status;
//call sproc
status=ValueReturnedFromSproc();
return status;
}
```

If you are wondering how the UI handles all this it can do so by this:

```
BLL b = new BLL();
if (!(b.IsValid(someRandomForumID)))
  Response.Write("Sorry you've got an invalid forumID");
else
  {
    //proper forum id go ahead...
  }
```

**In response to your edit:**

If you are actually exposing the ID in the URL and allow someone to change it then your on load event needs to simply pull the ID (request parameters) and check if it is valid.  If it is show the data if it isn't redirect to a page that states "Opps it appears you are trying to access a forum / thread that does not exist".

Comment: By looking at your example it appears that it’s still up to UI layer to call these validation functions? Thus if UI layer doesn’t call these functions first but instead calls method A (in BLL layer), then all bets are off? So validation logic shouldn’t be contained inside method A (nor should method A call these validation functions), but instead I should create separate functions for validating the ID and it is up to UI to call them?

Comment: Just because the UI instantiates the BLL does not mean its going directly to the DAL.  How else are you going to validate?  1st you shouldn't rely on end users typing in ID numbers, they could be problematic and invalid.  You should write the UI so that they can only select valid ones.  In addition, fill a list, a grid or a drop down list with active valid ID numbers.  Then you do not have to check if they are valid or not.

Comment: What if some third party wants to build UI on top of my DAL and BLL. Would they expect I provide validation methods, which they(the UI layer) must call or would they expect that method A(which moves the thread) to call the validation logic?

Comment: @carewithl - I think you should realize most people will not buy a custom DAL and BLL, they are just too application specific.  You will end up redoing the DAL and BLL for any client.  Internally it all doesn't matter.  Most companies prefer ORMs anyhow so your DAL will be useless.  I am not saying anything you are doing is not useable.  I think what you are doing is great, you are learning how tiers / layers work.  Just know that the UI calls the BLL and the BLL calls the DAL.  The DAL sends a response back to the BLL and the BLL feeds it to the UI.  The UI doesn't know anything about SQL.

Comment: The DAL doesn't know anything about CSS and the BLL is simply the mediator between the two.  If you need to validate an ID create BLL instance and call function isValidID.  In the BLL the isValidID function simply creates a DAL instance and calls a method isValidID which gets an ID passed to it.  It performs some SQL operation, like checking whether an ID exists, and returns true or false back to the BLL.  The BLL wraps that up and sends it back to the UI (the client).  It's really that simple.

Comment: "If you need to validate an ID create BLL instance and call function isValidID."But should isValid be called by A(method which actually moves the thread) or by UI layer?

Comment: @carewithl - i cant make this any simpler...in UI you simply say `BLL b = new BLL(); bool isValid = b.IsValid(YourForumIDOrThreadID);`

Comment: So you won't think I'm completely retarded - I do understand how to invoke BLL layer and how isValid should be implemented and that isValid should contact DAL etc, I was just confused whether UI layer should have an option to call or not to call isValid.Namely, if isValid is called inside A, then UI doesn't really have say in whether isValid should be called or not

Answer (score 3):

You should do validation at all layers of the application. I would recommend that the BLL provide a couple of functions such as

bool ConversationThread.Exists(threadID)

bool Forum.Exists(forumThreadID)

The UI layer can then call these functions defensively to make sure that the input is valid. These functions in the BLL would probably delegate to similar functions in the DAL.

Additionally, in the DAL you should also do the same validation, and throw an exception if the validation fails, because in reality, you should do validation at all layers of the application

Comment: "The UI layer can then call these functions defensively to make sure that the input is valid. These functions in the BLL would probably delegate to similar functions in the DAL." A) But then it’s still up to UI layer to call these validation functions? Thus if UI layer doesn’t call these functions first but instead calls method A (in BLL layer), then all bets are off? B) So validation logic shouldn’t be contained inside method A (nor should method A call these validation functions), but instead I should create separate functions for validating the ID and it is up to UI to call them?

Answer (score 3):

If you have any rules about which threads can be moved to which forums, they should be in your business layer. Otherwise your errorhandling should cover the case where you attempt to handle non-existing threads or forums, as your database should give you a foreign key constraint error upon attempting to insert the invalid row.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't check in the lower layers, however you could consider adding constraints in the database so that an error is thrown in this situation.

I would consider the ability to pass invalid IDs a bug. I would attack that issue by making it so that it is virtually impossible for your upper layers to pass down bogus IDs.

EDIT:

To clarify, I don't think it's a bug to read/query with a nonexistent ID because it's just a query that has no results. However, I consider it a bug to allow an update with a non-existent ID. If the only way to get an ID for an update is from an existing database record, you don't need to ask the database if that record exists unless you are doing hard deletes (which is not something I'd recommend for a forum).

The other issue you brought up is about concurrency:

> But even if user chooses IDs from a
>   set of list, by the time it posts the
>   page back, the DB table containing
>   this ID could be changed in the mean
>   time by admin or whomever?!

To solve this problem you put either a timestamp or a rowversion on your forum and thread objects. If the timestamps no longer match the corresponding columns in the database when you do an insert, you should throw a concurrency exception. If they are still equal, you should do the update and increment the timestamp or rowversion column. You can learn more about this by googling [C# Optimistic Concurrency](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+optimistic+concurrency).

Comment: @Daniel Auger - You stated "I would attack that issue by making it so that it is virtually impossible for your upper layers to pass word bogus IDs." But you fail to explain how you would accomplish that.  I'll +1 you if you give details to the OP that shows how you would do that.

Comment: If the user is choosing a thread and a forum ID from list or set of lists, you can assume the list is populated with the correct IDs from the database. If they aren't, it's a bug. It's difficult to give more advice without seeing some code.

Comment: But in this case it doesn't look like the ids are in any sort of list.  If they were one could only assume that this would never happen as I assume the lists would be populated by a stored procedure or a DAL procedure that pulls all valid IDs.

Comment: In case you find the time...I've edited my initial post in response to your reply

Answer (score 1):

Some other good answers here, I'll reiterate a couple of thoughts.  Yes, you should validate (and handle/throw exceptions) at each layer, and you should be consistent with the kind of validation you will perform at each layer.

For example, you probably want validation in the DAL and datastore/sproc layers to be concerned with data integrity, so that you can reliably retrieve and manage forums and threads.  In the BLL, the validation should be mostly concerned with business rules (what constitutes conditions where a thread can move from one forum to another).  In the UI, the validation should be mostly concerned with user actions.  Generating IDs and thread move operations should be provided by lower layers.